# exclude headers on different path

Tags: http-headers, acl, haproxy

I am running haproxy 1.6.3 and I have the X-Frame-Origin headers set on the frontent. I just come across the situation when the site is loaded in a iframe and the content is blocked because of that header. I have tried to setting an acl rule which looks as the following:

```
acl is_embeded path_beg /?embeded=1
http-response set-header x-frame-options "SAMEORIGIN" if !is_embeded
```

when I run `haproxy -f /etc/haproxy/haproxy.conf -c` I for the following error:

```
[WARNING] 316/145915 (23701) : parsing [/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:42] : acl 'is_embeded' will never match because it only involves keywords that are incompatible with 'frontend http-response header rule'
```

Is there a way to get this work?

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using a request acl in response stage.

You need to stroe the url like this:

```
http-request set-var(txn.urlEmbeded) url
acl is_embeded var(txn.urlEmbeded) -m beg /?embeded=1
http-response set-header x-frame-options "SAMEORIGIN" if !is_embeded
```

also you are using path, it does not include the query. you might need to use `url` or `query`(embeded) with `found` method. You get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

There are actually two problems with what you are doing.

First, the `path` fetch is only available during request processing -- not response processing.  This is the reason for the warning.  The `path` isn't allocated a buffer of its own -- the fetch just extracts it from the pending request buffer whenever it's evaluated, and that pending request buffer is released as soon as the request had been sent to the server.

Second, everything beginning with `?` is **not** part of the path.   That's the query string.

The `capture.req.uri` is the correct fetch to use, since it includes both the path and the query string, and since a memory buffer is allocated for it, it persists during request processing.

```
acl is_embeded capture.req.uri -m beg /?embeded=1
```

> `capture.req.uri`
>
> This extracts the request's URI, which starts at the first slash and ends before the first space in the request (without the host part). Unlike `path` and `url`, it can be used in both request and response because it's allocated.
>
> http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.6/configuration.html#7.3.6-capture.req.uri

Also note the correct spelling for the word `embedded`.